# Can you lift a lie-algebra automorphism to a lie-group automorphism of a torus?

Tags: exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is known that given any lie-group homomorphism $g:G \to H$ is is possible to define a unique lie-algebra homomorphism $dg : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$ that satisfies

$$\exp (dg(v)) = g(\exp(v))$$

My question is, when is it possible to do the reverse direction, if we are only talking about automorphisms of some torus. More explicitly, if $dg : \mathfrak{t} \to \mathfrak{t}$ an lie-algebra homo' from the lie algebra of some torus to itself, when is it possible to define $g: T \to T$ s.t.

$$\exp (dg(v)) = g(\exp(v))$$

Comment: The usual condition is for the Lie group to be simply connected, which of course a torus is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For concreteness we'll just talk about $T^n$ regarded as the quotient $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$, with Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the endomorphisms of the Lie algebra give the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and the condition that such an endomorphism descends to the torus is precisely the condition that it lie in the subring $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

For an abstract torus $T$ the condition is that an endomorphism $f : \mathfrak{t} \to \mathfrak{t}$ must preserve the lattice $\pi_1(T)$, embedded as a subgroup of $\mathfrak{t}$.